# How to mark special theorems with star?

Tags: theorems, labels

In LaTeX, how can I give stars to some theorems that are somehow special theorems?

Like

Theorem 1.1. This is a normal theorem.

Theorem 1.2*. This is a special theorem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us whether you employ a package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem` to set up theorem-like environments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs the `amsthm` package and creates a copy of the `plain` theorem style, called `special`, which shares all the properties of the `plain` style except that it inserts a raised, bold `\asterisk` after the theorem number. The code can handle the case of a special-theorem with an optional argument/name; see the third example below.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm,bm}
\newtheoremstyle{special}% name
    {\topsep}%   Space above
    {\topsep}%   Space below
    {\itshape}%  Body font
    {}%          Indent amount
    {\bfseries}% Theorem head font
    {}%          Punctuation after theorem head -- blank
    {0.5em}%     Space after theorem head (0.5em is the default)
    {{\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{ #2$^{\bm*}\!$.}\thmnote{\ \textmd{(#3)}}}}% Theorem head spec 

% Set up two theorem-like environments:
\theoremstyle{plain}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\theoremstyle{special}
\newtheorem{spthm}[thm]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\stepcounter{section}
\begin{thm} This is a normal theorem. \end{thm}
\begin{spthm} This is a special theorem. \end{spthm}
\begin{spthm}[Euler] $\exp(i\pi)+1=0$. \end{spthm}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheoremstyle{special}
    {\topsep}
    {\topsep}
    {\itshape}
    {}
    {\bfseries}
    {\,\(\star\).}
    {.5em}
    {}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\theoremstyle{special}
\newtheorem{thm*}[thm]{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\begin{thm}
This is a normal theorem.
\end{thm}
\begin{thm*}
This is a special theorem.
\end{thm*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How would you handle the case of a theorem-like environment with an optional argument, say, `\begin{thm*}[Pythagoras] ... \end{thm*}`?

Comment: I guess the easiest way to handle that case would be to change the ``special`` theorem style: replace ``{\,\(\star\).}`` with ``{.}`` and replace the last argument with ``{\thmname{#1} \thmnumber{#2\,\(\star\)} \thmnote{\textnormal{(#3)}}}``.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to have the references typeset. If you also want an asterisk when the theorem is cross-referenced, the following is sufficient. It also works well with `cleveref`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newenvironment{theorem*}
 {\expandafter\def\expandafter\thetheorem\expandafter{\thetheorem*}\theorem}
 {\endtheorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{theorem}\label{normal}
This is a normal theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}\label{special}
This is a special theorem
\end{theorem*}

\ref{normal} and \ref{special}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want that the cross-reference is without the asterisk, you can do as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\let\standardthetheorem\thetheorem
\def\starredthetheorem{\standardthetheorem*}
\newenvironment{theorem*}
 {\labelformat{theorem}{\standardthetheorem}%
  \let\thetheorem\starredthetheorem
  \theorem}
 {\endtheorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Test}

\begin{theorem}\label{normal}
This is a normal theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{theorem*}\label{special}
This is a special theorem
\end{theorem*}

\ref{normal} and \ref{special}

\begin{theorem}
This is another normal theorem
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

This does not work with `cleveref`, though.

[image]

Comment: With your current setup, `\begin{theorem*}[Euler]` places the final period (in **bold**) after "(Euler)" instead of after "<num>*".

Comment: @Mico That's what `amsthm` always does.